# Python RAKE: TypeError: Unable to give parameters to the function

Tags: python, rake, typeerror

I know this question has been asked previously but it hasn't helped me so far.

1) I installed rake using the following command:
pip install python-rake

2) Next, I imported rake (I am using Ipython Notebook). I tried several options as mentioned below. The first two worked fine and gave no error.

- import RAKE.RAKE as rake
- import RAKE
- import rake (This gives me an error - No module named rake)

3) Finally, I want to create a rake object using the following command but I am getting an error

> rake_object = rake.Rake("StopList.txt",5,3,4)
>
> Error: TypeError                                 Traceback (most
>   recent call last)  in ()
>   ----> 1 rake_object = rake.Rake("C:\Users\kdudani\Desktop\StopList.txt",5,3,4)
>         2 rake_object
>
> TypeError: **init**() takes exactly 2 arguments (5 given)

I am following this [tutorial](https://www.airpair.com/nlp/keyword-extraction-tutorial)

Just to let you know, I searched for solutions elsewhere and this is what I found on another [website](https://github.com/fishkao/rake/issues/1).
Not sure if this is an issue Rake that hasn't been resolved.

Comment: Any suggestions?

Comment: I faced with the same problem, any suggestion?